# UIButton to update UITableView in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I'm wondering how I can use a `UIButton` action function to be able to press a button so each time it is pressed, a new row in a `UITableView` is added. Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to set an IBOutlet for your UITableView.
2. In the IBAction of the UIButton, add a value to the data structure you used to implement the cells of the tableview.
3. Then call reloadData() function for the tableview outlet

   That is, in code

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
   {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) 
       cell?.textLabel = dataStructure[indexPath.row]
       return cell
   }
   ```

For the IBAction

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
         dataStructure.append(someNewValue);  // someNewValue is the new Value for the row
         table.reloadData()
    }
```